# jQuery UI sortable - trigger a sortable event when manually moving an item from one list to another

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, triggers, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-events

How do you trigger a jQuery UI sortable event with out the user dragging and/or dropping an item?

Here is an example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eBnVJ/15/).

When you click the button any "selected" items in "List A" will be moved to "List B".  However no sortable event is triggered.

Comment: It looks like your example is working for me using Chrome but I don't see a button like you stated in your question. Perhaps you're missing some code?

Comment: Sorry it appears that jsFiddle didn't save my changes after I forked someone else's.  Luckly I have found that triggerhandler("sortreceive") does what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, what I would do is create a method that gets called whenever the sortable `receive` event is fired or when the "move all" button is clicked.

### [Here's a fiddle with an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/6FZ3b/1/)